# Proving that $(X,d)$ is a topological space

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, metric-spaces

I'm really new to topology and struggling with understanding the concept of it. I have the following example but I don't know how to go about and show that it is a topological space.

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space, with the set $X$ uncountable. Let $\tau$ denote the collection of all subsets $\mathcal{O}$ of $X$ such that for each $x\in \mathcal{O}$ there exists $r>0$ and an at-most countable subset $A$ of $X$ such that $x \notin A$ and $B(x,r) \setminus A \subseteq \mathcal{O}$. Then $\tau$ is a topology on $X$.

Now to show that $\tau$ is a topological space we firstly need to show that $X \in \tau$ and $\emptyset\in\tau$. Here's my attempted proof:

Fix a point $x \in X$, and suppose $A$ is countable so that $A=\{a_1, a_2, \ldots \}$ with $a_i\in X$ for each $a_i$. Since $(X,d)$ is a metric space, there exists some $r_0>0$ such that $B(x,r_0)\subseteq X$.   Pick $$0<r< \min \{d(x,a_1),d(x,a_2), \ldots,r_0\}.$$ Such an $r$ exists since $x \notin A$, so $d(x,a_i)> 0$ for all $i$. Thus $B(x,r)= B(x,r)\setminus A\subseteq B(x,r_0)\subseteq X$, so $X \in \tau$.

However I don't know whether it is a good proof. What I did was just to make sure that the ball $B(x,r)$ does not contain any elements in $A$. Firstly, why should $X$ be uncountable and does $A$ have to be at-most countable? Secondly, why is $\emptyset$ an element in $\tau$ as apparently there is no element in $\emptyset$ that satisfies the definition of $\tau$? Finally, I noticed that  the collection of $x$ contains the closure points of $\mathcal{O}$ that belongs to $\mathcal{O}$ (since $B(x,r)\cap\mathcal{O} \neq \emptyset $). Is this helpful in the proof?

Comment: Note : $\mathcal O$ is a set of sets.  If $x$ is a point of $X$, please don't write $x \in \mathcal O$ but $x \in O$ and $O \in \mathcal O$.

Comment: From the definition, I thought $\mathcal{O}$ is just a subset of $X$, and $\tau$ is a set of sets. Am I wrong?

Comment: Ah, no, okay, I misunderstood.  I usually uses $\mathcal O$ for the set of open sets.

Comment: For proving $X \in \tau$... I believe $B(x,r) = B(x,r) \setminus \varnothing \subseteq X$ for any $x \in X$

Comment: $\emptyset \in \tau$ iff for each $x\in X$ the following statement holds: if $x\in \emptyset$ then something. $x$ is never in $X$ so the statement always holds and $\emptyset \in \tau$

Comment: The "min" of an infinite number of positive reals might be $0$.

Comment: @mathworker21 Correct me if I'm wrong. If $\inf d(x, a_i)=0$, then $\min d(x,a_i)=\inf d(x,a_i)$ iff $\inf d(x,a_i) \in \{ d(x,a_i)\}$. But if $\min d(x,a_i)=\inf d(x,a_i)=0$, then $x=a_i$ which contradict to $x \notin A$.

Comment: @user46666 The min wouldnt be 0 - it just wouldn't exist. $0 = \inf \{1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\dots\}$ but is not the min.

Comment: @mathworker21 Thanks! So such an $r$ may not exist even if $a_i$ is countable...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A set $O$ is open iff for *all* $x \in O$, there is some $r_x>0$, $A_x \subseteq X$ countable with $x \notin A_x$ (both $r$ and $A$ can depend on the $x$ chosen, hence my notational choice of using subscripts) such that $B(x,r_x)\setminus A_x \subseteq O$.

Note the similarity to the definition of the metric topology w.r.t. $d$: there $O$ is open iff for *all* $x \in O$ there is some $r_x$ such that $B(x,r_x) \subseteq O$. In the variation we allow for a countable set of exceptional points from the open ball that need *not* lie inside $O$. The condition that $x \notin A_x$ ensures that $x$ itself cannot be one of those exceptional points so $x \in B(x,r_x)\setminus A_x$ is garantueed (and this must hold as $x \in O$ to start with).

Moreover, if $X$ were countable, we could take $A_x=X\setminus\{x\}$ for all $x$ and $r_x=1$, say, and then $B(x,r_x)\setminus A_x = \{x\}$. The openness condition then reduces to $\forall x \in O: \{x\} \subseteq O$ which holds for any $O$ so we would get the discrete topology. The proposer of this topology wanted to avoid this trivialised case, I suppose. The set $X$ is "big" (uncountable) and the exception sets should be "small" (at most countable).

That $O=X$ is open is trivial and needs no fancy arguments, just use $r_x=1$ and $A_x= \emptyset$ and note that for all $x \in X$, $B(x,1)\setminus \emptyset = B(x,1) \subseteq X$ by definition; nothing to prove.

For $O = \emptyset$ we have a case of [vacuous truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth) where a statement where we want a property to hold for all $x \in O$ is true if there are no $x \in O$ at all.

The union axiom is also quite easy (look up how the argument went for metric topologies) and likewise for finite intersections (intersections of two sets suffice to check this axiom). Try it.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation! It helps tremendously. So essentially I can fix $A=\emptyset$ and this topology "becomes" the metric topology?

Comment: @user46666 There is no global set $A$ in this problem, the set $A$ depends on $x$ and $r$. In fact the set $A$ contains $ B(x, r)\setminus{\cal O}$.

Comment: @user46666 yes, all metric open sets are also open in this topology. But all countable subsets are closed as well. So it’s a strictly finer (larger) topology than the metric one.

Comment: @Gribouillis but *if* we'd fix it globally we'd get the metric topology, is what I think he's asking.

Answer (score 0):

The proof is not good because you don't understand the definition of the collection $\tau$. I think it is easier to rephrase  the definition by $\cal{O}\in\tau$ if and only if for all $x\in \cal{O}$, there exists $r>0$ such that $\cal{O}^c\cap B(x, r)$ is at most countable, where $\cal{O}^c$ denotes the complement of ${\cal O}$. In the case ${\cal O} = X$, it it obvious because $X^c = \emptyset$. In the case $\cal{O} = \emptyset$, it is obvious because there is no $x$ in $\emptyset$.